# Order by multiple values from sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table Estates: `[Id, Title]` and Results: `[EstateId, Type (nvarchar), A (int), B (decimal)]` and a query similar to this:

```
select *
from Estates
order by (
    select A
    from Results
    where Type = 'some dynamic value'
    and EstateId = Id
) ASC, (
    select B
    from Results
    where Type = 'some dynamic value'
    and EstateId = Id
) DESC
```

The query plan says that both subqueries are run, and I would like to know if there's a way to rewrite it to order by multiple result values from a single subquery.

I have tried concatenating to a string (with leading zeroes for natural sorting), but the ascending/descending part is hard. I have also tried hierarchyid, but it does not support zeroes after the dot (the fractional part of the decimal).

Any good ideas?

This is a dynamically built query, and though I could refactor it to make it join the Results table, it will make the code quite weird in other places because I already join the Results table but with another value of Type. Therefore I hoped for a sub-query solution.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: If the "some dynamic value" is the same in both queries you can join the table and use as many columns as you like

Comment: Also with no `ORDER BY` the `TOP (1)` value will be completely arbitrary, which means that the order of your data is *not* deterministic, and could change everytime you run the query.

Comment: I think you're doing something weird, why not just join A and B table normally, and then use the field in order by.

Comment: You could start by specifying table names in your queries. I don't think any version of SQL Server actually likes `... FROM WHERE ...`

Comment: @DaleK This is a dynamically built query, and though I could refactor to make it join the Results table, it will make the code quite weird in other places because I already join the Results table, but with an other value of Type. Therefore I hoped for a sub query solution.

Comment: If you can refactor to join that's the best solution (IMO), even if occasionally weird. At least with the information provided.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks. What do you mean by "At least with the information provided."? :)

Comment: @ThomA As for TOP 1, there will always be only one result, but I was under the impression that this knowledge would be useful for the query optimizer. I may be mistaken :)

Comment: Well you aren't showing your actual query nor showing the dynamic nature, so any suggestions are only based on what you have posted

Comment: Don't use top 1 unless you need to - and in general don't use any performance tips unless they solve an actual performance issue

Comment: If you're using `TOP (1)` then it implies that the query could return more than 1 row and so you're intentionally limiting the rows, asgerhallas . If you *know* that the (correlated) query can't return more than 1 row then you shouldn't use `TOP`, as @DaleK suggests; it makes things confusing (as it implies a one/many-to-many relationship) and when you omit an `ORDER BY` therefore suggests non-deterministic results.

Comment: @DaleK "in general don't use any performance tips unless they solve an actual performance issue". I am solving an actual performance issue, and I'm in the process of trying out different solutions and measuring them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values A and B are numeric and you already tried to get from, say, 12 and 125 to '0001200125' for a sortkey, then getting a descending order key is not that difficult. In my example you would calculate 99999 - 00125 and end up with '0001299874'.

In below query I use a 20-digit sortkey composed of two 10-digit parts:

```
select *
from estates
order by (
    select format(a, 'd10') + format(9999999999 - b, 'd10')
    from results
    where type = 'some dynamic value'
    and estateid = id
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm after - and it seems to work, except for `format(9999999999 - b, 'd10')` which returns `NULL` for the decimal column, so I changed it to `'00000000000.00000'` instead of ´'d10'´.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Just make sure to use the matching digits-9 number, for your <11>.<5> key, you'd have `format(99999999999.99999 - b, '00000000000.00000')`.

Comment: I tried that, but it seem like I need more zeroes than nines. If I use the same number of decimals, values for b between -1 and 0 orders after even smaller numbers.

Comment: Ah, okay, I assumed positive Bs only. You are right, with negative numbers we need one zero more. If Bs range from -9999999999.99999 to +9999999999.99999 (i.e. ten digits before the decimal point), then `9999999999.99999 - B` will result in sortkeys '19999999999.99998' down to '00000000000.00000' and we need the pattern '00000000000.00000' (i.e. eleven digits before the decimal point).

Comment: Well the fact that you only mention the values of A & B that you are using now, in the comments,  is an example of lacking details. A [mre] in your question would have been much clearer.

Comment: @DaleK I'm all for making it clearer, if I can, but it felt like some commenters did not even try to understand my intentions before asking for details, which I did not know how to provide, or which were not actually relevant to the problem - BUT I could have tried harder, I admit. Sorry about that. Can you elaborate on "the fact that you only mention the values of A & B that you are using now, in the comments"? Do you mean that saying `int` and `decimal` columns wasn't enough information abount range, precision and sign? I get the need for better sample data though. So, point taken!